# Last breaking changes to Ada

Tags: ada, backwards-compatibility

*(Edited to narrow the question to Ada. Have posted other questions for [Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160619/last-breaking-changes-in-fortran) and [COBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160574/most-recent-breaking-changes-to-cobol).)*

I've spent some time in the past year dealing with changes to my code due to Python v2->v3 and R v3->v4 changes. It got me curious as to some of the older languages that are still in use.

I know Ada still sees occasional updates and functionality upgrades. I would assume that their mission-critical nature makes those changes smaller and more backward-compatible, but I don't really know and couldn't find it with a web search.

What and when were the last changes to Ada that was on the same rough order as the Python 2->3 changes?

Comment: The Fortran standardization committee goes to great lengths to maintain backwards compatibility with previous Fortran standards.  Standard conforming Fortran 77 will likely compile with a compiler conforming to the Fortran 2018 standard.  There are no instances that are comparable to the python 2 versus python 3 fiasco.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/tour this site does not cover the question asked. Other than this I'd say the same as Brian (Ada) and evets (Fortran) about COBOL...

Comment: There are valid Fortran 66 programs which aren't valid F77 programs; valid F77 programs which aren't F95; F95 and F2008 which aren't F2018.  And many Fortran programs change their interpretation under different language revisions. However, "same rough order" would seem to be rather open to personal interpretation.

Comment: Probably worth turning a couple of these comments into answers; I don't know Fortran well enough to describe it in mine, or Cobol at all.

Comment: @BrianDrummond And that nicely shows why the question is too broad. It should be asked per-language.

Comment: Cobol, Fortran and Ada are completely different in terms of specialization and age. For instance Ada is much more recent than C, so it has enjoyed from the beginning the experience about portability, standardization, modularity etc. that the "oldies" (Cobol, Fortran, C) could have at their respective times.

Comment: @Zerte you could hardly call C an oldie in the terms of Fortran or Cobol. My first edition K&R (1978) isn't all that long before the preliminary Ada standard (December 10, 1980)

Comment: To my knowledge C was already around in the early 1970's as a PDP-11 macro-assembler. Perhaps you should compare the K&R edition with the first "Programming in Ada" books. Anyway, my point was rather that the standardization effort has been late, at least for Fortran and C, with a clear impact on portability.

Answer (score 6):

Ada pays a lot of attention to reverse compatibility, to avoid breaking existing code, when making changes.

Last formal Ada release was [Ada-2012](https://www.ada2012.org/), there is [another one (Ada-202X)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/ada2x.html) in progress.

Ada-2012 has a lot that Ada-83 doesn't, but I'd be surprised if there was anything more than trivial work to build an Ada-83 project (or Ada-95 or Ada-2005) in Ada-2012.

There are some differences though : [from Ada-83 to Ada-2012](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/compatibility_and_porting_guide.html#compatibility-with-ada-83) As you can see, there's really not much to say for 30 years of development.