# Most recent breaking changes to COBOL

Tags: cobol, backwards-compatibility

I've spent some time in the past year dealing with changes to my code due to Python v2->v3 and R v3->v4 changes. It got me curious as to some of the older languages that are still in use.

I know COBOL still sees occasional updates and functionality upgrades. I would assume that their mission-critical nature makes those changes smaller and more backward-compatible, but I don't really know and couldn't find it with a web search.

What and when were the last changes to COBOL that was on the same rough order as the Python 2->3 changes?

Comment: COBOL74 to COBOL85, in ... 1985. Dropped a bunch of the existing syntax.

Comment: I looked up COBOLin Wikipedia to be sure.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL  @SimonSobisch is correct. 
 COBOL 2002 didn't change anything in most COBOL shops, and I never heard of COBOL 2014.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming problem as defined in the Help Center but a computer history question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What and when were the last changes to COBOL that was on the same rough order as the Python 2->3 changes?

What was changed is a long list, therefore not shown.

COBOL 2002:

Removed 18 language elements that were made obsolete in COBOL 85.

Added 54 reserved words that would cause syntax errors if not used in conformance with the 2002 standard.

Added the `FLAG-85` directive to identify 10 cases where the same syntax could have different results than the 1985 standard.

Comment: And you consider this "the same rough order as the Python 2->3 changes?"

Comment: Note (to the question + answer): The COBOL standard N is in general quite different from Python M. The later is an implementation of the language. Most implementations of COBOL that actually do support COBOL 2002 (I'm not sure if there's any implementation that claims to fully support it, which was one of the reasons that the COBOL2014 standard made some COBOL2002 features optional) have the removed language elements still in, as "an extension to the Standard" - which is completely fine.