# Last breaking changes in Fortran

Tags: fortran, backwards-compatibility

I've spent some time in the past year dealing with changes to my code due to Python v2->v3 and R v3->v4 changes. It got me curious as to some of the older languages that are still in use.

I know Fortran still sees occasional updates and functionality upgrades. I would assume that their mission-critical nature makes those changes smaller and more backward-compatible, but I don't really know and couldn't find it with a web search.

What and when were the last changes to Fortran that was on the same rough order as the Python 2->3 changes?

Comment: While I think there are useful things to say (considering now a single language), I feel the reference to "same rough order" is unnecessarily limiting. Can you rephrase to support more objective answers?

Comment: If you are asking for some drastical changes as disallowing the original default syntax of the print statement and changing the meaning of a basic arithmetic operator than the answer is never. Or if yes, than in the very old days before standardization (1966). Since than only really obsolete features get deprecated and eventually deleted.

Comment: If you, however, want to ask for progressive changes, adding new features, there are many. Fortran 90 and 2003 were particularly rich in this.